# Unequal load balancing with balance-rr mode on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bonding

Have two network cards bonded in a balance-rr configuration:

```
root@server:~# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:76:c7:cc:8a:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:76:c7:cc:8a:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:76:c7:cc:8a:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The bond works great and is configured below via netplan:

```
network:
ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
        dhcp4: false
    enp1s0:
        dhcp4: false
version: 2
bonds:
    bond0:
         interfaces: [enp0s31f6,enp1s0]
         addresses: [10.0.10.10/16]
         gateway4: 10.0.0.1
         mtu: 9000
         nameservers:
              addresses: [10.0.0.1]
         parameters:
                 mode: balance-rr
                 mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

However I'm noticing something peculiar. When transferring large files through NFS from a single server (10G connection) I achieve 180MB/s max, with ~120MB/s coming through enp0s31f6 and ~60MB/s coming through enp1s0. If I unplug enp0s31f6, the other interface, enp1s0 achieves maximum throughput at 120MB/s.

Any idea why the load appears to be distributed in a 2:1 ratio?

Comment: I can't give you right answer, but may be these cards have different count of input/output queues.

Comment: How could I check that? Is it something I can update?

Comment: Command: `cat /proc/interrupts`. See also https://support.scalearc.com/kb/articles/how-to-distribute-irq-affinity-using-script

Comment: I assume they advertise the same link speeds?